# Other than HTMLTestRunner

Tags: python, selenium

I want to generate a report of selenium script which is written in python. I have not used unittest, so is there any other way of generating report other than HTMLTestRunner?

Comment: Try using nose-html-reporting 0.2.3, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-html-reporting

Comment: I have not used unittest, so I guess nose will not be a solution for me.

Comment: check this, https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki, if it's not suited ur req then suggest create your own report at the run time

Comment: "Other than HTMLTestRunner" is not a question. Please fix the question title to be an actual question so it's more useful to those coming later.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/).  Behave has custom formatters.  Also see [here](https://testingbot.com/support/getting-started/behave.html).